# Riverpod notifier provider call function

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I have been using provider as state management and had newly migrated to riverpod. Riverpod has a lot of providers which is confusing for me. I am using NotifierProvider and have issue calling a function

Here is the screen and the function. I wanted to access the update function but i can only access the model variables. Error says ***"The getter 'notifier' isn't defined for the type 'SignupModel'"***

```
    class SignUpScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = Screens.signUpScreen;

  @override
  ConsumerState<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends ConsumerState<SignUpScreen> {


 onSubmit() async {
    LoggerService.log(LogEventType.ButtonPress,
        LogDetails(buttonName: 'onSubmit', displayName: 'Sign Up Screen'));
    final registerChangeNotifier =ref.watch(registerChangeNotifierProvider);
    //can't call update function
    ref.read(registerChangeNotifier.notifier).update()
  
    try {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate() && isChecked) {
        //Close keyboard
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
            .pushNamed(EmailOtpScreen.routeName);
      }
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      LoggerService.log(
          LogEventType.Warning,
          LogDetails(
              error: e,
              message: e?.toString() ?? e?.toString(),
              stackTrace: stackTrace));
    }
  }
```

here is the provider

```
class RegisterProvider extends Notifier<SignupModel> {

  @override
  SignupModel build() {
    return SignupModel(email: '');
  }

  void update() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider):

> `ref.watch` is used inside the `build` method of a widget or inside the body of a provider to have the widget/provider listen to a provider

If you want to call the `update` method from your `Notifier`, use the same way as the docs demonstrated how to call the `increment` method [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refread-to-obtain-the-state-of-a-provider).

That is, in your case, the way to call it is:

```dart
ref.read(registerChangeNotifierProvider.notifier).update();
```

and remove the `ref.watch` line.

---

I suggest you to familiarize yourself with the use of `ref.watch`, `ref.read`, `ref.listen`, notifiers and providers from the [documentation](https://riverpod.dev/) in general.